# HTTParty: Upload files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, carrierwave, httparty, fog

How would I do the following `curl` call using [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)?

```
$ curl -u andrew.lunny@nitobi.com -F keystore=@android.keystore -F 'data={"title":"Android Key","alias":"release", "key_pw":"90123456","keystore_pw":"78901234"}' https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
HTTParty.post("https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android?auth_token=#{phonegap_token}", query: { keystore: file }, body: { data: {
    title: 'Android Key',
    alias: '...',
    key_pw: '...',
    keystore_pw: '...'
} }, format: :plain)
```

`file` is a `Tempfile` object which I fetched from the cloud storage where the file is located.

I want to pass a file which has been uploaded using Carrierwave and stored using Fog. Do I have to fetch it first from the URL?

Comment: The url you post is different in curl and httpparty. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is going to work however you can try:

```
HTTParty.post("https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/android",  
  body: { 
    data: {
      title: 'Android Key',
      alias: '...',
      key_pw: '...',
      keystore_pw: '...'
    }.to_json,
  keystore: File.read(file)
  })
```

Comment: Here is the response: `"{\"error\":\"\xFE\xED\xFE\xED\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\[...]\u0001h蓍\x84q\x9B\xF1\xE2\xEA\u0019v\xC0yh\u0003\xAF@ͮ\xD3R\x87/jO\xAE\u001C@a\xF0H\xC1\xD2A\u0016 is not a file\"}\n"`

Comment: I also tried to use a URL: `{"error"=>
  "https://...keystore/13/key.keystore is not a file"}`

Comment: I cant test however I would use a library that does multipart like https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client